# How do you deploy two or more applications that use Firebird Embedded databases on the same machine?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird, firebird-embedded

Suppose I have three separate applications called **MyPasswordManager**, **MyToolManager** and **MyMovieManager**. Each of these applications uses a **Firebird Embedded** database.

If a customer buys all three of my aplications and installs them on his/her computer. And my customer has all three applications running at the same time, what happens?

Will the Firebird dll's have conflicts? What do you do in this situation?

Comment: You can share the same firebird embedded dll with several databases, without any problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you put the Firebird dll's in the application folder (where the .exe is) there won't be a problem since this is the first place where your application will look for them.

You have to make sure that the applications each install to their own folder, if you want to use different versions of the dll's.

Answer (score 3):

Cape, you really ought to read the "readme_embedded.txt" file in the doc directory - it has all the answers youre looking for. Some relevant quotes (for the FB 2.5 version):

> 2.2. Database access
>
> The database file can be accessed by multiple client
>       programs. The database consistency in this case is
>       guaranteed internally (by the shared lock table).
>
> 2.4. Compatibility
>
> You may run any number of applications with the embedded
>       server without any conflicts. Having IB/FB server running
>       is not a problem either.

Comment: I usually do RTFM and would have RTF "readme_embedded.txt" if it was included in the 2.1 download zip. I haven't downloaded 2.5 yet, perhaps I should. It just struck me as a bit odd that a I couldn't find an answer to my questione here - http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ufb-cs-embedded.html

Comment: @Cape There are several improvements in FB2.5 regarding the embedded server. BTW AFAIK the "readme_embedded.txt" is only in the embedded server download.

Answer (score 2):

have you tested it in your dev machine? I think just putting the apps and the dlls in different folders each one could work. Maybe renaming the dlls with different names can work too

Comment: No I haven't tested it on my machine. I'm thinking a few steps ahead. I purchased Delphi 2010 Professional which does not come with a Firebird DBExpress driver. So, I'm trying to decide if I should use Firebird and if so which driver to buy. I'm strongly leaning toward Devart IBDac or UniDac. Because I'm looking for an embedded database solution I'm also considering NexusDB.